# Subordinate clause forms

Tags: subordinate-clauses

I wasn't sure about the subordinate clause forms, so I searched on google and found a website that has examples.
http://chompchomp.com/terms/clause.htm
In this website, it says the general forms are following:

1. Main Clause + Ø + Subordinate Clause
2. Subordinate Clause + , + Main Clause

Does the form depend on the subordinate conjunction that is being used? What I mean by this is, if you're using the subordinate conjunction, whenever, are you bound to use form 1 or can you use form 2 also?

For examples on the website:

1. **Whenever lazy students whine, Mrs. Russell throws chalk erasers at their heads.**
2. **Anthony ran for the paper towels as cola spilled over the glass and splashed onto the counter.**
3. **Because my dog loves pizza crusts, he never barks at the deliveryman.**

Is it still correct if you change the their forms?

1. **Mrs. Russell throws chalk erasers at lazy students whenever they whine.**
2. **As cola spilled over the glass and splashed onto the counter, Anthony ran for the paper towels.**
3. **My dog never barks at the deliveryman, because he loves pizza crusts.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewrites are all syntactically fine, but it might be objected that the last one creates an ambiguity: is it the dog or the deliveryman who loves pizza crusts?

You should be aware, however, that the site you link employs the term *subordinate clause* in an unusual sense. It is true that these days there is very little standardization in English grammar; but I think that every contemporary linguist would call **all** of the clause types identified there *subordinate clauses*.

The term *subordinate conjunction* for *whenever, as, because* is also unusual: it is the clauses which follow these words which are "subordinate", while the words themselves in traditional grammar are called *subordinat**ing** conjunctions*. However, many contemporary grammars discard this term and classify almost all such words as *prepositions*.

Comment: Do you know a site you recommend?